# MVC 5 Keep User logged when browser is restarted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

First of all, I'm new to MVC, but I managed to create a simple custom login using Entity Framework, MVC 5 and C#. ( I do not want to use Identity because the idea is to get to know the functions behind it).

I'm currently doing this with Session Variables, so when the user exist in the DB, I store the info like Role, Name, etc. in Session Variables, but when the user closes the browser or I restart the app the session is lost so the user has to login again, how can I prevent that from happening and keep the user logged like Identity does?

Comment: Do the same thing Identity does, Cookies :)

Comment: Session variables are not persistent through browser restarts, they're only valid for that "session". Using [cookies](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/), you can customize exactly how long this information is stored.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out!

Comment: @GregoryHouseMD: The only thing Identity uses cookies for is the auth token. Storing anything other than that in a cookie (role, name, etc.) is a *hugely bad idea*.

Comment: I know that it is a bad idea, but it is the only solution to his problem. The Identity cookie is enough to restore those variables when the session restarts and there's no need for an extra cookie

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion about how authentication and sessions actually work here.

First, sessions utilize cookies. That's how they work. A cookie is set with the session identifier so that the server can retrieve the appropriate session with each subsequent request. The only alternative is what's referred to as "cookie-less sessions", where the session identifier is passed around as a query string parameter. However, these are generally discouraged because inevitably the URL leaks and its far too easy to hijack user sessions this way.

Second, sessions on the server are *not* the same thing as a browser "session". The server-side session does not expire when you close your browser. That's just patently false. You *can* however, have the cookie containing the session identifier be set as a "session cookie", which causes the cookie itself to expire when the browser session ends. The server session still exists, only without the cookie, there's no way to look it up. However, you can just as easily have the cookie expire after a period of days or weeks. The fact that it's a cookie used to maintain a session doesn't necessitate that it be a "session cookie".

Third, there's different mechanisms of session storage. The default, because it requires no configuration, is what's called "in-proc". That means the session data is stored in memory by the web server process. When the web server process is terminated, its memory block is freed, along with your session data. Persistent sessions require persistent storage, meaning something like a database.

Long and short, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, you just don't have your sessions configured properly. Refer to the [MSDN docs on the `<sessionState>` Web.config element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx). You'll need to add something similar to:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
              cookieless="false"
              timeout="3600"
              sqlConnectionString="[Connection String Here]" />
```